# Processing AWS Athena result with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

We are using Amazon Athena for some analytical processing. Athena produces CSV into S3 bucket, which we process with Python. This works until we use composite values as query result.

It seems that Athena uses some SerDe format (I suspect it's SimpleLazySerDe, but it's hard to find that in official documentation).

Is there any library for Python that is capable of deserialising composite types in CSV that's produced by Athena? And is it really SimpleLazySerDe or another (maybe even standard) format?

An example query

```sql
SELECT ARRAY[1,2,3] as array,
       ARRAY[ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY[3,4]] as array_of_arrays,
       ARRAY[MAP(
         ARRAY['a'],
         ARRAY['1']
       )]
```

Produces this CSV

```
"array","array_of_arrays","_col2"
"[1, 2, 3]","[[1, 2], [3, 4]]","[{a=1}]"
```

It's apparent that format used by Athena for complex values is not any standard format (not JSON, YAML, etc). Without specification, grammar, it's hard to parse it because without knowing all specifications for separators, escaping literals, it would be trial and error. Please note that the query is only an example to produce complex values so everyone can take a look and provide information what format that is and how to parse it.

Please note that I don't search answers for how to orchestrate Athena runs with Python nor some workarounds like CTAS. My original question is

- what format is it
- is it standard format
- is there any Python library that is capable of SerDe operations on top of it

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example of these "composite values"? FYI, you can execute Athena commands from Python using [`start_query_execution()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution), checking with `get_query_execution()` and retrieving results with `get_query_results()`. This avoids conversion to CSV files.

Comment: Another option is to create a table for output and insert data using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`. The format that this table uses to store data can be defined when the table is created, including ORC, Parquet and Avro. See: `STORED AS` in [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)

Comment: I am not searching for workarounds (we already have those in place). I need to know the root of the problem - what is the SerDe format used by Athena and how to read it in Python.

Comment: can you give an example of the SerDe operation you would like to perform?

Comment: Example query and data sample added into original question

Answer (score 0):

I think [awswrangler](https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please give an example how awswrangler could be used to deserialise that specific format? I found that it can be used to run Athena queries into data frames, which is not exactly what this question was about - how to read csv with composite values produced by Athena engine.

Comment: Can you give an example (output) of the deserialization you would like to run?

Comment: Example query and data sample provided in original question

Comment: I saw that, I just do not understand what you would like to do with that CSV

Comment: The query shows several types of composite data (array, arrray of arrays and map). I have been asking for formal specification of the format, because without grammar or spec, it's not that easy to parse it (I don't know all the escaping rules, etc). So I just gave an example for everyone if they know the format and whether there is any library that's able to parse that string into native objects, preferably in Python

Comment: would a pandas DataFrame qualify as a native object? if not, what do you see as a native object, something like a native datatype (list, tuple, dictionary..) I guess?